# to change the date format in data base

Tags: mysql, forms, date, datetime, yii

it is not able to store day,month,year in the format of dd/mm/yy in data base by getting value through the form of Yii.it is only possible to store in the format of year/month/date can any body answer.

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: i need to change the date format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd by using code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. I am guessing when you save date submitting the form it saves in mysql default format and then when you display it, it is not displayed in your desired format. If this is the case, I would recommend the best way to solve this is to change the date format in the model. You can use the 'before save' and 'after find' methods in the model to change the date format before saving to db and also change it when it is pulled from db. The actual date format will remain the same in db, but it will also display in the format you want it to. Here's an example,

```
protected function beforeSave()
    {
        if($this->date!=null){
        $this->date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->date));
        }
    return TRUE;
    }
    public function afterFind()
    {
        if($this->date!=null){
        $this->date = date('d F Y',strtotime($this->date));
        }
    return true;
    }
```